# what does it mean [ WARN:0] terminating async callback?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i use videocapture in python by cmd but i got this message when it return

c

[ WARN:0] terminating async callback

d

this is my code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import sys

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        print('a')
        break
print('c')
cap.release()
print('d')
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

my python version 3.7.0

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: the problem is why it will display [ WARN:0] terminating async callback? and how to fix it?  @mypetlion